# Convert array of keys-value pairs: keys for values, and values for unique keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I would like to convert an array of arrays that is functioning as a key-value store.

Each sub array takes the following form: `['tom',['hello','world']]`, where the `[0]` index (`'tom'`) is the 'key', and the `[1]` index (an array) is the 'value'.

I want all of the 'values' in my array to be unique keys of a new array, and the keys in my array should construct new sub-arrays containing all of the previous keys which held the corresponding value.

For example:

```
var myArray = [
    ['tom',['hello','world']],
    ['bob',['world','foo']],
    ['jim',['foo','bar']]
];
```

The above input should achieve the following output:

```
var newArray = [
    ['hello',['tom']],
    ['world',['tom','bob']],
    ['foo',['bob','jim']],
    ['bar',['jim']],
];
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting to the 'solution', I'd like to address the fact that this is very poor way to store and describe data. If you're looking for something similar to associative arrays from `PHP`, you should learn how to [work with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Objects in JS are simply a collection of unique-key (properties) -> value pairs.

As objects, your data sets would look like this:

```
var before = {
  tom: ['hello','world'],
  dick: ['world','foo'],
  harry: ['foo','bar']
};

var after = {
  bar: ["harry"],
  foo: ["dick", "harry"],
  hello: ["tom"],
  world: ["tom", "dick"]
};
```

Here's an implementation using objects. Also naive, but so much simpler.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/pitico/1/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```js
var before = {
  tom: ['hello','world'],
  dick: ['world','foo'],
  harry: ['foo','bar']
};

var after = {
  bar: ["harry"],
  foo: ["dick", "harry"],
  hello: ["tom"],
  world: ["tom", "dick"]
};


function resObj(obj) {
  var o = {};
  
  for (var k in obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj[k].length; i++) {
      o[obj[k][i]] = o[obj[k][i]] || [];
      o[obj[k][i]].push(k);
    }
  }
  
  return o;
}

console.log('Expected:', after);
console.log('Actual:', resObj(before));
```

---

Below is an example of how to do what you want with arrays. It's naive, slow, and I'm sure it could be improved, but that's kind of beside the point of my answer.

A rough demo. Note that we use an object as an interchange, making it almost the same as above.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/xazusu/1/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```js
var inp = [
    ['tom',['hello','world']],
    ['dick',['world','foo']],
    ['harry',['foo','bar']]
];

var out = [
    ['hello',['tom']],
    ['world',['tom','dick']],
    ['foo',['dick','harry']],
    ['bar',['harry']]
];

function resArray(arr) {
  var q = {},
      o = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i][1].length; j++) {
      q[arr[i][1][j]] = q[arr[i][1][j]] || [];
      q[arr[i][1][j]].push(arr[i][0]);
    }
  }
  
  for (var m in q) {
    o.push([m, q[m]]);
  }
  
  return o;
}

console.log('Expected:', out);
console.log('Actual:', resArray(inp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, you are essentially asking to compute the inverse of a many to one relation. You can think of the relation as a mapping from a pair of objects. Logically, you are mapping "tom" to "hello" and "world". The inverse relation will map "hello" and "world" to "tom".

When you think of "relations", you should think of associative containers instead of arrays. Using arrays makes your algorithms much more inefficient unless your keys are densely packed integers.

This produces the correct output:

```js
var myRelation = [
  ['tom', ['hello', 'world']],
  ['dick', ['world', 'foo']],
  ['harry', ['foo', 'bar']]
];

function inverse(relation) {
  // This first half does the hard work of computing the inverse.
  var intermediate = {};
  relation.forEach(function(outerEntry) {
    outerEntry[1].forEach(function(innerEntry) {
      if (!intermediate[innerEntry]) {
        intermediate[innerEntry] = {};
      }
      intermediate[innerEntry][outerEntry[0]] = true;
    });
  });
  // This second half turns the intermediate assocative container
  // back into an array of nested arrays.
  var output = [];
  Object.keys(intermediate).forEach(function(outerEntry) {
    output.push([outerEntry, []]);
    Object.keys(intermediate[outerEntry]).forEach(function(innerEntry) {
      output[output.length - 1][1].push(innerEntry);
    });
  });
  return output;
}

console.log(inverse(myRelation));
```

If you drop the need to reproduce the original output format in arrays, the problem becomes a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here a clean a implementation of your conversion function.

```
/**
 * Converts from a one-to-many to many-to-one relationship.
 * @param  {[array]} pairs [array representing a one-to-many relationship.]
 * @return {[array]}       [array representing the same data, in a many-to-one relationship]
 */
var oneToManyFlip = function(pairs){
  //Recall that current[0] is our 'key'.
  //Also recall that 'prev' is the empty object we passed in.
  var result = pairs.reduce(function(storage, current, index, array){ 
    current[1].forEach(function(element, index){
      if(storage[element] === undefined){ storage[element] = [];}
      storage[element].push(current[0]);
    });
    return storage;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(result).map(function(element){
      return [element, result[element]];
    });
}
```

I hope it's a little cleaner and easy-to-reason-about. Map & Reduce can be a little tricky to get your head around at first.

You can learn more about functional JS [here](http://jcouyang.gitbooks.io/functional-javascript/content/en/higher_order_function/high-order_function.html). It's useful for these kinds of computations on iterables.